# HelloSign python SDK generated with OPS is different from the SDK project provided in github

Tags: python, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli, hellosign-api

I am trying to generate the python SDK of the hellosign from the opensource repo with this yaml https://github.com/hellosign/hellosign-openapi/blob/main/openapi-sdk.yaml

The below is the command I am using to generate the SDK

> java -jar openapi-generator-cli-6.6.0.jar generate -i D:\openapi-sdk.yaml -g python -o c:\temp\hellosign_python --skip-validate-spec --additional-properties packageName=hellosign.sdk

But the SDK project generated is different from the once they have generated here https://github.com/hellosign/hellosign-openapi/tree/main/sdks/python.

Few API classes are not there. **init**.py is different with separate clients and so on. How to generate the SDK project same as they have generated?

Comment: Their [Readme](https://github.com/hellosign/hellosign-openapi#changes-to-generated-sdk-code) mentions that they use custom templates for OpenAPI Generator.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to generate the Python SDK by running the `./generate-sdk -t python`

As stated in the [readme](https://github.com/hellosign/hellosign-openapi/tree/main#rebuilding-sdks).

You should also be able to generate it from within the [Python SDK](https://github.com/hellosign/dropbox-sign-python) repo by running `./run-build`